# compare the coefficient of $x^2$ in $\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wrote $\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$ as $(\frac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} -1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} +1)......$
(because roots of tanx/x are n*pi , where n is any integer)

> $$
>     \frac{\tan(x)}{x} = (\frac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} - 1 )(\frac{x}{3\pi} +1)...\\
>     \frac{(x+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15}...)}{x} = (\frac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} -1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} +1)...\\
>     1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{2x^4}{15}...    = (\frac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} -1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} +1)...
> $$

if i compare the coefficient of $x^2$ from both sides,
i get a contradicting result for sigma $(\frac{1}{r^2})$.
Could somebody check the mistake for me please?

(However if i compare the coefficients $x^2$ in $\frac{(\sin(x))}{x}=(\frac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} - 1)(\frac{x}{2\pi} + 1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} -1)(\frac{x}{3\pi} +1)...$ then i get the correct result, i.e., sigma$\frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{(\pi^2)}{6}$

Comment: What is $r$? How can (x/pi -1)(x/2pi -1)(x/3pi -1) = 
(sinx)/x **and** = (tanx)/x. And please use Latex: Is
x/3pi $= \frac{x}{3\pi}$ or  $=\frac{x}{3}\pi?$

Comment: First, the infinite product $(x/\pi-1)(x/(2\pi)-1)(x/(3\pi)-1)\dots = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{x}{k\pi}-1\right)}$ doesn't converge, since the terms converge to $-1$. You should be looking at $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)}$. Secondly, is there any reason you *should* expect $(\tan x)/x = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)}$? It is true that $(\sin x)/x = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)}$, but that's more of a miracle thanks to complex analysis.

Comment: Without MathJaX it is going to be really hard to understand what you really meant...

Comment: Sorry, it had some error i've corrected it now.

Comment: plz check it again

Comment: this is a reference....
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach

Comment: You might want to consider that $\tan(x)$ has poles / singularities, so your product expansion ought to incorporate those too.

Comment: You still think the expressions of $\frac{\tan x}x$ and $\frac{\sin x}x$ as infinite products coincide?

Comment: The simple answer is to take the expansion of $\tan$ and find the coefficient of $x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

You are tacitly assuming that $\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$ is an entire function, but that cannot hold since such a function has plenty of singularities along the real line. A correct approach is to start with the Weierstrass product for the cosine function
$$ \cos(x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
and consider $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides, leading to:
$$ \tan(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8x}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2 -4x^2}\tag{2}$$
Dividing both sides by $x$ and writing the terms of the series in the RHS as geometric series, we get:
$$ \frac{\tan x}{x}=2\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{x^{2m}}{\pi^{2m+2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2m+2}}\tag{3} $$
and since:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2m+2}} = (4^{m+1}-1)\,\zeta(2m+2) \tag{4} $$
it follows that:
$$ \boxed{\frac{\tan x}{x} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{2(4^{m+1}-1)\,\zeta(2m+2)}{\pi^{2m+2}}x^{2m}} \tag{5}$$
and the coefficient of $x^2$ in the RHS of $(5)$ is given by:
$$ \frac{2\cdot 15\cdot\zeta(4)}{\pi^4} = \frac{2\cdot 15}{90} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.\tag{6}$$

This is usually exploited in the opposite direction, i.e. by noticing that the values of the $\zeta$ function at the positive even integers are given by the Taylor coefficients at $x=0$ of $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ or $x\cdot\cot(x)$.

Comment: Interesting way of getting $\tan$ out of $\cos$ while changing the product into a sum.

Comment: nice analysis..

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio
i understand that tanx/x is discontinous at (2n+1)pi/2 but what if i consider x between 0 and pi/2 (both excluded), 
then my polynomial way of expressing it should work right?

Comment: @AishitDharwal: no, due to the principle of analytic continuation. If your identity was correct in a open neighbourhood of the origin, it would fix the values of $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ also outside that neighbourhood.